# List has No Rows for Assignment to SObject: Error

Tags: apex, trigger, sobject, object

I have below trigger code where I get "List has No Rows for Assignment to SObject"

Apex trigger:

```
trigger CallVisibility on Compliance_Incident_Transaction_abv__c(before insert, before update) {

    // List<Compliance_Incident_Transaction_abv__c> olis = [SELECT Id, Call_Account_abv__c,Call_Load_abv__c, Account_abv__c,Ownerid FROM Compliance_Incident_Transaction_abv__c WHERE Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()];

    for (Compliance_Incident_Transaction_abv__c o: Trigger.new) {

        //System.debug(o.Order_Phase__r.Order__Item__r.Order_Project__c);
        String Terr=[select territoryId from userterritory where userid=:o.Ownerid].territoryid;
        String TerrName=[select name from Territory where Id=:Terr].Name;
        if(o.Call_Account_abv__c!=null) {
            String ATL= [select Territory_vod__c from Account_Territory_Loader_vod__c where Account_vod__c=:o.Call_Account_abv__c limit 1].territory_vod__c; // This line throws error
            if(ATL.contains(TerrName))
                {o.Call_Load_abv__c=true;}

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty self explanatory - you don't have any `Account_Territory_Loader_vod__c` records with a value for `Account_vod__c` that matches `o.Call_Account_abv__c`. Try debugging the values for the two fields and you'll get insight into what's going wrong

Comment: I noticed in your query you're selecting `Territory_vod__c` but then using `Account_vod__c` in your WHERE clause. Is that intentional?

Comment: n.b. Some vbl name improvements are in order -- (1) `Terr` should be `terrId`, (2) `ATL` should be something like `terrVod` as you are returning fields, not records in the left hand side of your assignment statements

Comment: you are also doing soql inside of a for loop -- not best practice at all. Review doc on how to bulkify triggers by using maps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root cause of your issue is that you're assigning the result of a list into a singleton, and when there's no values returned, a QueryException is thrown.  See [these alternatives](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/system-queryexception-list-has-no-rows-for-assignment-to-sobject.html):

1)

```
try {

  String ATL= [select Territory_vod__c from Account_Territory_Loader_vod__c where Account_vod__c=:o.Call_Account_abv__c limit 1].territory_vod__c;
}
catch (System.QueryException e) {
  System.debug('caught ya!');
}
```

2)

```
List<Account_Territory_Loader_vod__c> atlv = [select Territory_vod__c from Account_Territory_Loader_vod__c where Account_vod__c=:o.Call_Account_abv__c limit 1];
if (atlv.size() == 0) {
  System.debug('nothin!');
} else {
  String ATL = atlv.get(0).territory_vod__c;
}
```

Comment: Ray - while these alternatives are good, the OP's issue was on the third SOQL.