# List has no rows for assignment to SObject when the value is returned

Tags: apex, error, sobject, error-messages

Why am I getting the error: `List has no rows for assignment to SObject`?

Here is the function which produces the error:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static void setCharacterPose(
        String interactionId,
        Boolean isLeft,
        String character,
        String pose
    ) {
        if(isLeft) {
            UPDATE new zced__Interaction__c(
                Id = interactionId,
                zced__Left_Character__c = character,
                zced__Left_Character_Pose__c = pose
            );

            List<Interactions_Relation__c> currentInteractionRelations = [
                SELECT Successor__c
                FROM Interactions_Relation__c
                WHERE Predecessor__c = :interactionId
            ];
            System.Debug('currentInteractionRelations' + currentInteractionRelations);
            for(Integer i = 0; i < currentInteractionRelations.size(); ++i) {
                Interactions_Relation__c cir = currentInteractionRelations[i];
                System.Debug('sdsdvsHERE');
                while(cir.Successor__c != null) {
                    Interaction__c nextInteraction = [
                        SELECT Id, Interaction_Type__c, zced__Left_Character__c, zced__Left_Character_Pose__c
                        FROM Interaction__c
                        WHERE Id = :cir.Successor__c
                    ];
                    System.Debug('nextInteraction' + nextInteraction);
                    if(nextInteraction.Interaction_Type__c == 'Transition') {
                        break;
                    }

                    nextInteraction.zced__Left_Character__c = character;
                    nextInteraction.zced__Left_Character_Pose__c = null;
                    UPDATE nextInteraction;

                    cir = [
                        SELECT Successor__c
                        FROM Interactions_Relation__c
                        WHERE Predecessor__c = :nextInteraction.Id
                    ];
                    System.Debug('cir' + cir);
                }
            }
        } else {
            UPDATE new zced__Interaction__c(
                    Id = interactionId,
                    zced__Right_Character__c = character,
                    zced__Right_Character_Pose__c = pose
            );
        }

    }
```

Here is the log after the execution:

> 20:11:38.0 (295643387)|USER_DEBUG|>[131]|DEBUG|currentInteractionRelations(zced__Interactions_Relation__c:>{zced__Successor__c=a0A1r00002rAxEqEAK, Id=a0B1r000017Gwk2EAC})

I am really stuck because I can not understand what is causing the error. As you can see from the log the `currentInteractionRelations` variable is initialized successfully. So, I would expect this code:

```
 for(Integer i = 0; i < currentInteractionRelations.size(); ++i) {
                    Interactions_Relation__c cir = currentInteractionRelations[i];
System.Debug('sdsdvsHERE');
```

to run without any problems. And it is not actually the case because the `sdsdvsHERE` does not get output to the log.

[This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84257/list-has-no-rows-for-assignment-to-sobject-error) answer does not help, because as you can tell from the log there is actually a returned value.

Here is what the function looks like after I made the changes suggested in the answer:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static void setCharacterPose(
        String interactionId,
        Boolean isLeft,
        String character,
        String pose
    ) {
        if(isLeft) {
            UPDATE new zced__Interaction__c(
                Id = interactionId,
                zced__Left_Character__c = character,
                zced__Left_Character_Pose__c = pose
            );

            List<Interactions_Relation__c> currentInteractionRelations = new List([
                SELECT Successor__c
                FROM Interactions_Relation__c
                WHERE Predecessor__c = :interactionId
            ]);
            System.Debug('currentInteractionRelations' + currentInteractionRelations);
            if(!currentInteractionRelations.isEmpty()) {

                for (Integer i = 0; i < currentInteractionRelations.size(); ++i) {
                    Interactions_Relation__c cir = currentInteractionRelations[i];
                    System.Debug('sdsdvsHERE');
                    while (cir.Successor__c != null) {
                        Interaction__c nextInteraction = [
                                SELECT Id, Interaction_Type__c, zced__Left_Character__c, zced__Left_Character_Pose__c
                                FROM Interaction__c
                                WHERE Id = :cir.Successor__c
                        ];
                        System.Debug('nextInteraction' + nextInteraction);
                        if (nextInteraction.Interaction_Type__c == 'Transition') {
                            break;
                        }

                        nextInteraction.zced__Left_Character__c = character;
                        nextInteraction.zced__Left_Character_Pose__c = null;
                        UPDATE nextInteraction;

                        cir = [
                                SELECT Successor__c
                                FROM Interactions_Relation__c
                                WHERE Predecessor__c = :nextInteraction.Id
                        ];
                        System.Debug('cir' + cir);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            UPDATE new zced__Interaction__c(
                    Id = interactionId,
                    zced__Right_Character__c = character,
                    zced__Right_Character_Pose__c = pose
            );
        }


    }
```

Here is an error I am getting now:
[image]

> Error:(126, 82) Expecting '<' but was: '('
>
> Error:(126, 74) Invalid type argument count for List: expected 1 but found 0

Comment: Seriously, don't use `List<sobjects> results = new list<sobjects>([query])`. It has no benefit other than bloating your code.

Comment: Plus it makes it just a tiny bit harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odds are, your problem lies with this line:

```
cir = [
    SELECT Successor__c
    FROM Interactions_Relation__c
    WHERE Predecessor__c = :nextInteraction.Id
];
```

If there's no record that matches the query, you'll get an exception. You can fix that up with:

```
Interactions_Relation__c[] cirSuccessors = [
    SELECT Successor__c
    FROM Interactions_Relation__c
    WHERE Predecessor__c = :nextInteraction.Id
];
if(!cirSucessors.isEmpty()) {
  cir = cirSuccessors[0];
} else {
  break;
}
```

Comment: Oh! Let me try it.

Comment: @oobarbazanoo Sorry, had the wrong data type in the list. I just edited it.